# Java Combo Box and MySql database

Tags: java

I am currently using netbeans GUI drag and drop form, i have a combobox, and i want the combobox value to change based on data received from a database. The other textboxes are receiving their data correcly, the main problem is with the combobox.

```
   String x = tI.getStatus();

   if(x == "Assigned"){
       cboStatus.setSelectedIndex(0);
   }
   else if(x == "In progress"){
       cboStatus.setSelectedIndex(1);
   }
   else if (x == "Pending"){
       cboStatus.setSelectedIndex(2);
   }
   else if(x == "Completed"){
       cboStatus.setSelectedIndex(3);
   }
```

can anyone tell me how to change the index of the combo box based on data received from database. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use `String.equals` to compare String content. The `==` operator compares `Object` references.

```
if (x.equals("Assigned")) {
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare Strings with `==`, use `equals()`

Comment: Yes thats true, i forgot about that. Its working now, thanks a lot man :) That was indeed a silly mistake :(

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.equals()`. The `==` operator compares if two Strings reference the same String object; not if they have equal characters in the String.